# VB.Net SQL insert from datagrid

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am currently building an application whereby a user inputs data into a grid and this is then inserted into a SQl table.
However i am having issues getting it to insert more than the top row. I get an error stating too many parameters have been declared for the procedure.
am trying to execute a loop with the insert occuring for each row. 
When run the top row is inserted but anything else is ignored

```
    For i = 0 To dgvRI.Rows.Count - 1
            sqlRI.CommandText = "dbo.vb_insert"
            sqlRI.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@accid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = accid
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@rnum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@rilim", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@riatt", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@rishare", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@rname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@bname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@cov", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@prop", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@loc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@con", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@prem", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value
            sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@curr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dgvRI.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value
            i += sqlRI.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new instance for each row, I think you object is adding same param everytime.

```
        sqlRI = new sqlRI();//create new instance everytime
        sqlRI.CommandText = "dbo.vb_insert"
        sqlRI.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlRI.Parameters.Add("@accid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = accid
```